# The value of Henry's sisters are $4$ more than his brothers. How many more are Marie's (who is Henry's sister) sisters than her brothers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

The value of Henry's sisters are $4$ more than his brothers. How many more are Marie's (who is Henry's sister) sisters than her brothers?

I'm really confused right now and don't know what to do. Can you assist?

Comment: This seems too complex, doesn't this?

Comment: Try examples:  Say Henry has $4$ sisters and $0$ brothers.  Then Marie has $3$ sisters and $1$ brother, so $2$.  If, on the other hand, Henry has $5$ sisters and $1$ brother, then Marie has $4$ sisters and $2$ brothers, so again $2$.  Take it from there.

Comment: @lulu Got it now ;)

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is meant to be read as "Henry has 4 more sisters than brothers. How many more sisters than brothers does Marie have?"
then you can note that there are $3$ more girls than boys, so Marie has $2$ more sisters than brothers.

Comment: How did you find that out? Oh got it now

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, take an example. Let's say there are 9 siblings. 6 of them are girls (Marie is one of them) and the rest 3 are boys (Henry is one of them).

Now Henry has 6 sisters and 2 brothers. He has 4 more sisters than brothers. That satisfies your condition.

Marie has 5 sisters and 3 brothers. She has 2 more sisters than brothers. That's your answer.

Also btw you can take many examples, 7 sisters and 4 brothers or 8 sisters and 5 brothers, the answer will always be the same.